# How is spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition related to spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled incase of spark streaming with Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write data into a Kafka topic after reading a hive table as below.

```
write_kafka_data.py:
read_df = spark.sql("select * from db.table where some_column in ('ASIA', 'Europe')")
final_df = read_df.select(F.to_json(F.struct(F.col("*"))).alias("value"))

final_df.write.format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker)\
        .option("kafka.batch.size", 51200)\
        .option("retries", 3)\
        .option("kafka.max.request.size", 500000)\
        .option("kafka.max.block.ms", 120000)\
        .option("kafka.metadata.max.age.ms", 120000)\
        .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 120000)\
        .option("kafka.linger.ms", 0)\
        .option("kafka.delivery.timeout.ms", 130000)\
        .option("acks", "1")\
        .option("kafka.compression.type", "snappy")\
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", oauth_config)\
        .option("kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class", "io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler")\
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "OAUTHBEARER")\
        .option("topic", 'topic_name')\
        .save()
```

After successful write (number of records are 29000), I am reading data from the same topic as below in another file:
read_kafka_data.py:

```
    # SCHEMA
    schema = StructType([StructField("col1", StringType()),
            StructField("col2", IntegerType())
    ])

    # READ FROM TOPIC
    jass_config = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required" \
                          + " oauth.token.endpoint.uri=" + '"' + "uri" + '"' \
                          + " oauth.client.id=" + '"' + "client_id" + '"' \
                          + " oauth.client.secret=" + '"' + "secret_key" + '" ;'

    stream_df = spark.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafka_broker) \
            .option('subscribe', 'topic_name') \
            .option('kafka.security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL') \
            .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', 'OAUTHBEARER') \
            .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', jass_config) \
            .option('kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class', "io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler") \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'latest') \
            .option('group.id', 'group_id') \
            .option('maxOffsetsPerTrigger', 200) \
            .option('fetchOffset.retryIntervalMs', 200) \
            .option('fetchOffset.numRetries', 3) \
            .load()\
            .select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias("json_dta")).selectExpr('json_dta.*')

    stream_df.writeStream.outputMode('append')
    .format(HiveWarehouseSession.STREAM_TO_STREAM)
      .option("database", "database_name")
      .option("table", "table_name")
      .option("metastoreUri", spark.conf.get("spark.datasource.hive.warehouse.metastoreUri"))
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/dir")
      .start().awaitTermination()
```

I am a beginner to Kafka and been reading Kafka performance optimisation techniques and came across these two.

> `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` and `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition`

To enable the first parameter:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled",”true”)
```

The explanation for the above parameter is given in the official documentation as:

> Enables or disables Spark Streaming's internal backpressure mechanism
> (since 1.5). This enables the Spark Streaming to control the receiving
> rate based on the current batch scheduling delays and processing times
> so that the system receives only as fast as the system can process.
> Internally, this dynamically sets the maximum receiving rate of
> receivers. This rate is upper bounded by the values
> `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` and
> `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition`

Now that I am running the application first time and there is no previous micro batch, should I specify some value for: `spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate`

If so, how should I determine the value of `spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate`.
The documentation also says that if `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` is set to `true` the maximum receiving rate is set dynamically.
If that is the case, do we still need to configure:
`spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` and `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition`
if `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` is set to `true` ?

This [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/enable-back-pressure-make-your-spark-streaming-production-lan-jiang) says there is no impact in using `spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate` when back pressure is applied.

Any help in clearing the confusion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configurations `spark.streaming.[...]` you are referring to belong to the *Direct Streaming* (aka Spark Streaming) and **not** to *Structured Streaming*.

In case you are unaware of the difference, I recommend to have a look at the separate programming guides:

- [Structured Streaming: processing structured data streams with relation queries (using Datasets and DataFrames, newer API than DStreams)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)
- [Spark Streaming: processing data streams using DStreams (old API)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html)

Structured Streaming does not provide a backpressure mechanism. As you are consuming from Kafka you can use (as you are already doing) the option `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` to set a limit on read messages on each trigger. This option is documented in the [Structured Streaming and Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) as:

> "Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally split across topicPartitions of different volume."

---

In case you are still interested in the title question

> How is `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` related to `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` in case of spark streaming with Kafka?

This relation is explained in the documentation on [Spark's Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> "Enables or disables Spark Streaming's internal backpressure mechanism (since 1.5). This enables the Spark Streaming to control the receiving rate based on the current batch scheduling delays and processing times so that the system receives only as fast as the system can process. Internally, this dynamically sets the maximum receiving rate of receivers. **This rate is upper bounded by the values `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` and `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` if they are set (see below).**"

All details on the backpressure mechanism available in Spark Streaming (DStream, not Structured Streaming) are explained in the blog that you have already linked [Enable Back Pressure To Make Your Spark Streaming Application Production Ready](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/enable-back-pressure-make-your-spark-streaming-production-lan-jiang).

Typically, if you enable backpressure you would set `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` to be 150% ~ 200% of the optimal estimated rate.

The exact calculation of the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) controller can be found in the code within the class [PIDRateEstimator](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.1/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/rate/PIDRateEstimator.scala#L80).

### Backpressure Example with Spark Streaming

As you asked for an example, here is one that I have done in one of my productive applications:

#### Set-Up

- Kafka topic has 16 partitions
- Spark runs with 16 worker cores, so each partitions can be consumed in parallel
- Using Spark Streaming (not Structured Streaming)
- Batch interval is 10 seconds
- `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` set to true
- `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` set to 10000
- `spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate` kept at default value of 100
- The job can handle around 5000 messages *per second* per partition
- Kafka topic contains multiple millions of messages in each partitions before starting the streaming job

#### Observation

- In the very first batch the streaming job fetches 16000 (= 10 seconds * 16 partitions * 100 pid.minRate) messages.
- The job is processing these 16000 message quite fast, so the PID controller estimates an optimal rate of something larger than the maxRatePerPartition of 10000.
- Therefore, in the second batch, the streaming job fetches 1600000 (= 10 seconds * 16 partitions * 10000 maxRatePerPartition) messages.
- Now, it takes around 22 seconds for the second batch to finish
- Because our batch interval was set to 10 seconds, after 10 seconds the streaming job schedules already the third micro-batch with again 1600000. The reason is that the PID controller can only use performance information from *finished* micro-batches.
- Only in the sixth or seventh micro-batch the PID controller finds the optimal processing rate of around 5000 messages per second per partition.